# Add seconds (in fixnum format) to a datetime, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I need to pass a variable to my view with Time.now + @seconds in time format (i.e. 12pm + 3600 seconds = **1:00pm**, which goes to the view).

```
Time.now + @seconds #seconds is a fixnum
```

doesn't work because "Time can't be coerced into Fixnum". How then can I generate this simple result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't barbeque me if this is wrong now but back when I was doing Rails you would just say `Time.now + @seconds.seconds` . Also `@seconds.seconds.from_now`

Comment: Hi Chuck, that doesn't seem to work because @seconds is just a fixnum like... 25, so Rails doesn't recognize 'from' or 'seconds' in context of a fixnum. I just need to add that fixnum to Time.now.

Comment: The second should work for you. I've updated the original post. Tested with Rails 2.3.5 via the script/console. You _do_ have to be in a Rails environment to use .seconds or .days or .hours.

Comment: Also, I messed up the syntax of from, it should have been from_now. from_now is an addition to Time and seconds is an addition to Fixnum within Rails

Comment: Rails monkeypatches Fixnums to add methods like #seconds and #days for easier time-related logic.

Comment: Note (Rails 5) if you add (x.seconds + DateTime.now)  you get the "can't be coerced into Integer" error.  Adding parenthesis around the seconds element doesn't help.  But if you reverse them to say DateTime + x.seconds, then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Today I learned that `(1.second + DateTime.now) != (DateTime.now + 1.second)`

to answer your question try using `Time.now + @seconds.seconds` or `Time.now + @seconds.to_i.seconds`

Answer (score 0):

Another example

```rb
DateTime.current + 20.seconds
=> Mon, 11 Jan 2021 18:06:04 +0000
```